# Precompiling GWAN applications

Tags: web-applications, packaging, g-wan

I would like to be able to pre-compile GWAN applications written in C, as I don't want to deploy my source code on the customer's servers.

I've read the documentation but can find no mention of how to do this. Is this even possible?

I suppose one idea is to create my functionality in a library and link to that from my GWAN script. Is that the best way?

Comment: I cannot edit my question (the link is un-clickable, only share is clickable). I suppose one idea is to create my functionality in a library and link to that from my GWAN script. Is that the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> pre-compile G-WAN applications written in C

You are right, writing your own `libraries` called from your scripts (servlets and/or handlers) is today's solution.

But we have worked hard to provide a better solution where *all* the application, including all the pre-compiled scripts and the static documents compressed and stored under the gwan/.../www G-WAN directory are also stored `into the G-WAN executable`.

Interpreted applications written in PHP, Go, Lua, Ruby, etc. would be compressed and encrypted, and be possibly tied to an application-defined license key to help developers sell their work.

The goal here is to make it bullet-proof for end-users to deploy custom applications, and to help G-WAN developers protect their intellectual property (source code, copyright, algorithms, etc.).

This feature will probably be publicly released next year.

First, we want to release a more general-purpose release of G-WAN, which will also be usable as a simple *"Nginx on steroids"* (lower RAM consumption, higher performance for al type of files, small and large) to satisfy the needs of most users.

Comment: Thanks. I can't seem to save this comment so I've no idea if it will be displayed. Don't know what's going on with SO (or me). Ah, maybe it was too short. Seems to be there, now.